# Canvas wrong clipping on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, clip

I'm trying to clip canvas with javascript, it work correct in Mozilla Firefox but there is rendering error on google Chrome (not the same). How can I fix it? Or what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/xranto/hmrx52nv/

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.save();                             
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(31, 145);
    ctx.lineTo(206, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(303, 57);
    ctx.lineTo(469, 378);
    ctx.lineTo(133, 538);
    ctx.closePath();                
    ctx.clip();                     
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);                               
    ctx.restore();
}


img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/fHaQvTc.jpg";
```

HTML :

```
<canvas id="c" width="495" height="654"></canvas>
```

[Rendering comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNUot.jpg)

> Mozilla version : 43.0.1 - Chrome version : 50.0.2661.87 m

Comment: So, what result are you getting, and what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: works for me in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.63

Comment: Result is here : [http://i.stack.imgur.com/qNUot.jpg]

Comment: @RolandStarke chrome 26 ??? it's 3 years old, you should consider updating your browser. But works also on v50, osX. OP, can you tell us which version you're using ? There were some bug reports around [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464244/html5-canvas-clip-javascript-issue-with-chrome) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756073/) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026145) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175526) ; may be related.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

instead of :

```
ctx.closePath();                
ctx.clip();                     
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);                               
ctx.restore();
```

I use :

```
ctx.closePath();                
ctx.fill();     
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
ctx.drawImage(img,0, 0);
```

Thanks everyone !!!